# How to create temp table in informix using java?

Tags: java, informix

SampleSQL.sql

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE_TMP(column1, column2, column3)with NO LOG;
```

My below code isn't creating the temp table, but when I execute the above SQL in Informix server it creates the table without issue.

```
Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

//Informix temp table creation
BufferedReader tempScriptReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SampleSQL.sql"));
String str;
StringBuffer tempTableQry = new StringBuffer();
while ((str = tempScriptReader.readLine()) != null) {
    tempTableQry.append(str + "\n ");
}
tempScriptReader.close();
stmt = conn.createStatement();
//prepStatement = conn.prepareStatement(tempTableQry.toString());
System.out.println(tempTableQry.toString());
stmt.executeUpdate(tempTableQry.toString());
```

Comment: How does `stmt.executeUpdate()` report errors?  Have you looked to see what errors it reports?  Why `executeUpdate()`?  Is there not a straight-forward `executeImmediate()`?  Is the SQL you show exactly what's in your file?  If so, you're missing the type information for the columns.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thanks for your response. stmt.executeUpdate() doesn't give any error. but when i try to insert values into temp table(TABLE_TMP here) system throws an error says "the specified table is not in the database". it seems executeUpdate doesn't create temp table. Any help on this appreciated.

Comment: Don't know — I've written little enough Java and no code using JDBC.  Does this tutorial on the use of [`executeQuery()` vs `executeUpdate()` vs `execute()` in JDBC](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/difference-between-executequery-executeupdate-execute-in-jdbc/) help at all?  AFAICT, you should be OK.  Have you printed out the string you're passing to `executeUpdate()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot insert records into this table, then maybe you try to insert them using different database connection. Temporary tables exist only during life of connection in which they were created.

Your code executes `CREATE TEMP TABLE ...` very well. You have some errors in your SQL statement which ends with syntax error from Informix:

1. Instead of underscore in `TABLE_TMP` use space, or replace text in other way as you should use `CREATE TEMP TABLE table_name ...`
2. You must provide column types. Instead of `column1, column2, column3` use `column1 int, column2 int, column3 int` (of course you can replace `int` with other SQL type)

I tested your code with:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TABLE_TMP(column1 int, column2 int, column3 int) with NO LOG;
```

and it works. I also tested that you can insert into this table:

```
...
stmt.executeUpdate(tempTableQry.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    int r = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO TABLE_TMP (column1, column2, column3) VALUES(" + i + ", " + i + ", " + i + ")");
    System.out.println("execute result: " + r);
}
Statement sq = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = sq.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_TMP");
rs.next();
int count = rs.getInt(1);
System.out.println("record count: " + count);
```

My results:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TABLE_TMP(column1 int, column2 int, column3 int) with NO LOG;
execute result: 1
execute result: 1
execute result: 1
record count: 3
```